# iron-ajax hitting an URL gives No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using `<iron-ajax>` like as :

```
<iron-ajax id="dataAjax" url={{url}} method="POST" handle-as="json" params="{{getParam()}}" on-response="createResp" last-response="{{ajaxResponse2}}"></iron-ajax>
```

When i Check in Network tab in Chrome, response is coming, but because of following error `createResp` does not execute.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://...URL.... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried with this:

```
_handleError:function(event){
        console.log(event.detail.request.xhr.response); //null
      }
```

but i got **null**, but in network tab i am able to see the response.

And also status is 200

Can anyone help me how to get the response.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty questions about this. What you are looking for is `Cross browser origin`. 
for example:

[How to solve No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in polymer-project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130939/how-to-solve-no-access-control-allow-origin-in-polymer-project)

[Allow cross origin - iron-ajax - Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40395809/allow-cross-origin-iron-ajax-polymer)

["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

I had same problem at the beginning. We are using JAVA Spring for rest API and we had to configure that server so it will accept requests from my url ( i am using virtual hosts because we have dynamic Ips in company).

You can try to use [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) but still with the same problem:

> In order for this to work, the server must also enable credentials by setting the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials response header to “true”.

Anyway using `iron-ajax` is not effective in your case. You should specify your own XMLHTTPRequest

Comment: "iron-ajax don't support" — If it didn't support it, it wouldn't complain about the permissions that allow it being missing from the server.

Comment: @Quentin ye sorry, didn't realize that. i was writing that article for a while and you are right. I just forgot to remove it :)

Comment: that can't happen at server side, but i am getting response 200 with data, but due to error in polymer , i am not able to show it

Comment: then i suggest you to try your own xmlhttprequest.. i have never heard about this. if you get 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error there is no chance to get also data. are you sure you are looking to the same request? can you screen network tab in developer tools in chrome?